# Origen de utilizar "sapo" como sinónimo de "soplón", "delator" o "chismoso"

Tags: vocabulario, modismos, expresiones, historia

El día de hoy en el trabajo, un compañero estaba leyendo algo en internet y al yo hacerle un comentario sobre lo que el estaba leyendo me dijo **"Que man tan rana",** con **rana** el me quiso decir prácticamente: **"Que man tan sapo"**. Esto me dejó pensando sobre el uso de la palabra **sapo** en si, me puse a leer el DLE y para mi sorpresa me di cuenta de que la RAE efectivamente le da la definición de **chismoso** o **soplón** a la palabra **sapo** y además que no solo en Colombia se utiliza esta expresión tan peculiar

> **sapo, pa**
>
> **12. m. y f. Bol., Col., C. Rica, Ec., Ur. y Ven.** Soplón, delator.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo se llegó a utilizar **sapo** como sinónimo de soplon, delator o chismoso?

No veo como un sapo se podría relacionar con estas palabras, mi teoría es que tal vez tendrá que ver con el [Saco vocal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saco_vocal) que tienen los sapos y que con este se usa de forma metafórica a un delator que casi ni se puede contener en hablar.

Comment: Es curioso que haya tantos animales soplones: rata, topo, sapo... no se puede fiar uno de ningun bicho ya <.<

Comment: En Chile también se usa, y es frecuente. Cuando sueltas alguna indiscreción (revelas un secreto, haces público algún defecto de alguien, etc.) te dicen: _muere de viejo y no de sapo_.

Comment: ¿Y no será que un sapo tiene **la lengua muy larga**?

Comment: @Rāhula "man" es un anglicismo muy utilizado en Colombia para decir "Hombre", lo que mi amigo me quiso decir fue "Que hombre tan rana".

Comment: @Jdamian También puede ser, creo que esa teoria es mejor que la mia.

Comment: La explicación que siempre me dijeron era que los sapos tienen la boca grande, así que al bocón incapaz de callarse se le dice sapo.

Answer (score 6):

Me parece que debe haber una analogía física y/o de comportamiento entre el animal *sapo* y el personaje *delator*, como ocurre con las innumerables referencias zoológicas que se usan como metáfora en el lenguaje cotidiano. Desconozco exactamente cuál es esa analogía, pero me parece que podría deberse a los siguientes rasgos del sapo:

- Su **lengua** hábil, larga y mortífera. El soplón es un profesional del *lengua*je que, igual que los sapos, saca su lengua para hacer daño y después la oculta. La imagen de la lengua (el órgano anatómico) siempre acompaña al mal uso de las palabras: ser *deslenguado*, *irse de lengua*, ser/tener *lengua larga*. Las serpientes y su *lengua bífida* también entran en este juego pero hacia otra dirección.
- Su **croar**, especialmente el nocturno. Como la delación, el croar de los sapos se da oculto en una oscuridad que proporciona anonimato. Cuando todos estamos en silencio, hay una voz que canta en algún lugar sin dar la cara.
- Su **postura** (o actitud): semioculto, algo camuflado, inmóvil para pasar inadvertido. (En esto se diferencian, a mi modo de ver, los sapos de las ranas.).
- Sus **ojos**. Tengo la idea de que los ojos de los anfibios son grandes y un poco sobresalientes. Los dibujos de sapos típicamente muestran sus ojos como fuera del cajón del cuerpo, y a veces son lo único que sobresale fuera del barro o del agua. Parece como que siempre te estuvieran observando, evaluando a escondidas, tal como los delatores.

Alguno de estos rasgos, o todos juntos, podrían hacer que los delatores fueran identificados con los sapos. Hay que agregar, por supuesto, que los sapos no son para nada unos animales agradables. Tienen mala reputación, provocan repulsión y son (o se cree que son) venenosos.

Answer (score 3):

En mi país, Bolivia, especialmente en la región oriental dónde se encuentra la mayor cantidad de estos animales, se tiene la creencia, muy acertada en su mayoría de veces, que los sapos "aparecen" en los jardines de las casas o en los lugares con mayor vegetación, cuando está próximo a llover. Siendo como "delatores" o "soplones" de la lluvia. Por esto pienso, que se llegó a apodar con su nombre a las personas con estas características.

Answer (score 3):

Maikel Ramírez y Ana María Ramírez, en su artículo *Metáforas y metonimias del delator en seis expresiones del habla cotidiana venezolana* (Revista de investigación, n° 79, 2013) recuerdan que cuando alguien en Venezuela habla de un delator, si quiere enfatizar aún más su componente negativo se refiere a él como 'sapo' ('sapa' en caso de una mujer).

Los mismos autores, en el artículo *Personificación y despersonificación en la metáfora del burro ignorante* (Letras, n° 93, 2015) apuntan una explicación que no por lógica deja de ser brillante:

> En cualquier caso, esta expresión metafórica dependía de otras metáforas, como la de considerar que quien delata tiene una lengua que excede el tamaño normal (‘eres un lengualarga’), o que deliberadamente la persona afloja la lengua recipiente del secreto (‘soltó la lengua’), o que la lengua no logra ser controlada (‘se le fue la lengua’). Como resultado, expresiones metafóricas más complejas surgían, tales como: ‘se le fue el yoyo’, ‘se le fue la alfombra’ y la que nos ocupa: ‘ser un sapo’, en razón de que este animal saca la lengua y la estira de manera extraordinaria.

De hecho, en varios países latinoamericanos una forma de referirse a los delatores es *lengualarga*.

Mario Bernardo Figueroa Muñoz, en su trabajo *La voz del delator* (2008) completa y añade razones:

> En Colombia, como en otros países de América Latina, el término ‘sapo’ ha tenido el destino de  servir para denominar al lambón, al delator, al soplón, al chivato, a aquel que se dedica  a “cantar”, acción definida por el Diccionario de la lengua española no solo como  “Formar con la voz sonidos melodiosos y variados”, sino también como “Descubrir o  confesar lo secreto”, “poner en evidencia”.

De lo extendido que está el término sapo para referirse a un delator, me gustaría resaltar que el Diccionario de la Lengua reconoce el verbo **sapear**:

> Chile, C. Rica, P. Rico y Ven. Entre delincuentes, acusar (‖ denunciar).

Existe, incluso, la forma **sapiar**, cuya definición podemos ver en el *Vocabulario de la jerga estudiantil de Bogotá* (1968), de Jaime Ocampo Marín:

> **Sapiar**. Delatar, no perder la oportunidad para denunciar a otros.

---

**Referencias y fuentes**

https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/4478169.pdf

http://revistas.upel.edu.ve/index.php/letras/article/view/5953

https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/23/TH_23_002_133_0.pdf

https://revistas.unal.edu.co/index.php/jardin/article/view/10049/

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, creo que lo más cerca a entender de dónde viene la expresión “No seas sapo” viene del italiano Sputtare il rospo (escupir el sapo) algo que no puedes contener y tienes que decirlo, no seas el que escupe el sapo, o finalmente no te conviertas en el animal que necesitas escupir para decir todo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre lo he entendido como que los sapos al saltar se 'entrometen' en cualquier lugar, asimismo las personas que se entrometen a una conversación. Hay una frase que tambien se usa para decir "que man tan sapo" y es "salte aquí,sapo"; pero me parece que la palabra cambia un poco su significado cuando se quiere decir que alguien es sapo en el sentido que es muy "lengua larga", que todo lo cuenta, aunque también hace una clara referencia al sapo, por su lengua.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que a los soplones se les dio esa definiciòn, por que son como los sapos, son gente toxica y venenosa, ademas son gente que inspiran muy poca o nada de confianza,por su bocota escupen mucho veneno. con la finalidad de perjudicar a otras personas en su beneficio.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Gracias por su respuesta, seria bueno si tiene una referencia.